# Inserting values to a text field SQLServer 2008

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, prepared-statement

I am using prepared statement to insert records to an SQL Server 2008 table.

My logic for genric insertion of values is first take the table meta date and get all the fields types, after that set valued to the prepared statemnt based on the field type.

This is an example for a "text"

```
if(table.type_list.get(i).toUpperCase().equals("TEXT"))
{
    type = java.sql.Types.CHAR;
        prd.setString(i+1, value);
}
```

My question is for a "text" field what is the type that i should use (i.e java.sql.types.???), and what kind of set should i use?

The one in my code example throw an exception: "String or binary data would be truncated".

Comment: I don't understand where you use the 'type'? I mean it declare type=java.sql.Types.CHAR but using nowhere in code block.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772594/what-is-the-java-sql-types-equivalent-for-the-mysql-text.) is very similar to yours.  The problem you're having is that `Types.CHAR` really is a single character (Where is a maximum length specified in your code?) and you're trying to bind a whole string.